# MoreNavigationController is messing up

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

When I press more, I get this view...

[image]

Why is the "Edit-bar" not at top? I mean why is MoreNavigationController not filling the entire screen?

When I click edit, I get this screen...

[image]

Now I can't click done.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!
Mojo

Comment: it looks like you're pushing one NavigationController onto another one so that they're nested

Comment: How is your UI structured?  Is there a UITabBarController inside a UINavigationController?  Explain that in your question if you can.

Comment: I need help with this as well, I have tried hiding the main navigationbar on "willBeginCustomizing.." which works for part 2 (edit controller) but i cannot interact with it. the "Done" button will not trigger it's events. The issue is the more controller is pushed onto the stack, but the edit controller is presented modally. if i can present the more controller modally in the first place it would solve my issue